# Build Android AOSP system.img from changed framework.jar

Tags: android, build-process, android-source

I'm trying to change something in `android.webkit` files in the android platform framework, and then use

```
mmm frameworks/base
```

to build this into the `framework.jar` file.

How do I build the `system.img` file so that this jar file gets linked? Also, without having to build the whole system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you note above you can `make snod` to just make the system image without dependencies.

You can `make out/target/product/your-device/system.img` which I *believe* will build a system image plus its dependencies, but nothing else.

Just `make` probably won't do what you want, because the Android build system will build everything, *even stuff which isn't a dependency* - it builds all the other packages just in case they are broken by changes to the APIs.

Answer (score 5):

According to [JBQ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/cxTQPbj7XW0):

> `make snod` is what you need. It means "system no dependencies", and it
>   assembles a system image from whatever modules you have build,
>   regardless of whether some of the modules that should be in the system
>   image are missing our out of date.

This worked for me.